# MIT Kerberos - kpropd does nothing

Tags: sockets, replication, kerberos, centos6, mit-kerberos

I'm attempting to start kpropd on a CentOS box.  It gives no status and doesn't start the process.  The exit code is "1"

I started it in debug mode:

```
kpropd -d -S
```

It shows:

> kpropd: Address already in use while binding listener socket

I don't see anything in netstat listening on port 754.  The system is a VM and has only eth0 and lo.  The krb5kdc is running correctly.

This is all local but I'll post the iptables entry anyway:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 754 -j ACCEPT
```

Any thoughts on what might be blocking the socket?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it took some doing but there were two problems.

First, starting kpropd manually with -d -S, the socket was getting blocked by /sbin/portreserve.  The port is normally released during the init script, so if you want to do this you have to stop portreserve temporarily, or release the port with /sbin/portrelease.  Recommend not leaving portreserve off though, only disable to test.

```
service portreserve stop
```

The real issue was that I didn't have a kpropd.acl, or rather had it named wrong.  Strange that "service" showed nothing, returned nothing.  In any case, after creating the file kprop now inits correctly.

```
/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kpropd.acl
```

I had to hack up the /etc/init.d/kprop file quite a bit to figure that out.